# Markers get removed when Google Map fragment is replaced

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have two fragments in my activity and one container. I show either of the two fragments based on user input. One of these fragments is Google Map fragment with a marker added and zoomed in at that marker.

I do the following:

1. Replace Google map fragment with fragment X.
2. Then replace fragment X with Google map fragment.

After these two operations, I dont see the marker on the map anymore and the map is also zoomed out.

Note that I do not create a new google map fragment when I do operation 2. The google map fragment is the same as the one that was being displayed before. Also, after replace, if I try to add a marker, then even that does not work.

Can some explain what is going on here. Is it that the map fragment gets destroyed when I replace it with fragment X?

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly are you 'replacing'? Code please!

Comment: I am simply initiating a replace transaction
`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.mlContainer, googlePlacesListFragment).commit();`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `replace` it is the same as calling `remove` and then `add` on a fragment. The old fragment in the container is removed and the new one is added. you need to save the data somewhere if you want to have it show again

Comment: Is the fragment object destroyed on `remove` and re-created on `add`?